# what's the default folder for new files in python?

Tags: python, file, location, file-handling

Hi I'm new on learning python and I'm learning python files handling.
the following code works fine. But I can't find the folder where python creates this file.
(I'm using Visual studio code )

```
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a") 
f.write("Now the file has new content ")
f.close()


f = open("demofile2.txt", "r") 
print(f.read())
```

Comment: Have you checked inside the folder in which the python script runs?

Comment: "file is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) " - You should always read the [docs for the code you're using](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file your code created should be same location as your python code

Comment: Thank you very much. I found it

Answer (score 0):

if you run this, you will know where the files are saved:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An Interpreter, when you try to open or create a file via your code, will always be pointing to your Current/Present Working Directory.

Use the below line to know your pwd via your py file.

```
os.getcwd()
```

Via Terminal (OSX/Linux):

```
pwd
```

Via CMD (Windows):

```
cd
```